# How to get index keys of map in flutter?

Tags: flutter

How to simple code result like this code?

```
for (var i = 0; i < mseq.length - 1; i++) 
{
     if (mseq.keys.elementAt(i).toString() == value)
       selectpage = i;
}
```

Comment: Map uses key-value pairs. You will need to give the exact key match to fetch the result or you can do a foreach over the values key, value and key-value.

Answer (score 1):

Maps are **not indexed**. You can't get index.